# How to correct this terrible mistake

Tags: ios

and I am total fresh in iOS development and  today during the programming ,I have found this kind of mistake " "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MSmeItem", referenced from:", does anyone could tell me what is wrong? It's kind of emergency, thank you very much!

Comment: You'll need to provide more information. Are you starting a new project? Or working with an existing one? Can you send the full error, and possibly a screenshot of your Xcode window so that we can get a better grasp of your project/configuration?

Comment: A class in itself is not an error. You need to do enough research so that you **actually understand** the error message.

Comment: You need to provide more information. A portion of your code could also help.

Comment: Post the complete error.  It looks as if it's a problem with linking.  Missing symbol?  Multiple definitions of symbol?  ...?

Answer (score 0):

This is a linking error and it appears because you didn't add the static library (.a file) or the framework (.framework file) in the `Build Phases`.

Go to Project Navigator -> select the project -> select your target -> from the top bar select `Build Phases` -> go to 'Link Binary with Libraries' section and add the framework/static library which contains `MSmeItem` class.